# Print largest two integers from a stream

Tags: java, homework, beginner

I'm writing a program for my intro to comp sci course where I'm supposed to prompt the user to enter a stream of integers, and then return the largest two. We were given the hint to use a scanner and a while loop with the condition `.hasnext`.

Please review my code:

```
package Homework;

import java.util.*;

public class Question1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please type your integers");
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int big = 0;
    int big2 = 0;
    while(kbd.hasNext())
    { 
       int num = kbd.nextInt();
       if(num > big) { // opens If statement
          big2 = big;
          big = num;
        } else if((num < big) && (num > big2))  {
           big2 = num;
        } 
    } 
    System.out.print(big);
    System.out.print(big2);
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is actually correct.  Perhaps you just don't know what to type in your terminal window to terminate the input stream.  After typing in your numbers, you need to send an end-of-file ("EOF") character.  On Unix, you do that by hitting <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.  On Windows, it's <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

Note that `System.in` is the program's "standard input" stream, which doesn't have to come straight from the keyboard.  You can also do

```
echo 3 1 4 1 5 9 | java Homework.Question1
```

or

```
java Homework.Question1 < numbers.txt
```

Therefore, `kbd` is a misnomer.  Try naming your Scanner more generically, like `scanner` or `input`.

You don't want to print your two numbers with no space in between.  It will look like one long number!

The placement of your braces is inconsistent, with the ones for the `main` function and the `else if` being closest to conventions.  The brace opening the `while` loop should be on the same line as the `while` keyword.  The brace closing the `if` block should be pulled further left, aligned with the `if` keyword, and `else` can come immediately after.

```
public class Question1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        while (...) {
            ...
            if (...) {
                ...
            } else if (...) {
                ...
            }
        }
        System.out.println(...);
        System.out.println(...);
    }
}
```

You have interpreted the exercise such that duplicate entries in the input are ignored.  That's the easier way.  If the exercise requires you to print the same number twice when there is a tie for the maximum, then the program is trickier to implement.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it right or not but `echo "3 1 4 1 5 9" | java Homework.Question1` is giving me `InputMismatchException` but `echo 3 1 4 1 5 9 | java Homework.Question1` [no double quotes] is giving me correct output...

Comment: @tintinmj Oh, you must be on Windows, with different quoting behaviour. I put the double quotes there out of habit on Unix. They aren't necessary, so I'll edit them out of my answer.

Comment: Yes I'm working in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

```
package Homework;
```

Just for reference, package names are supposed to be lowercase and give information about the origin or author of the package, for example:

```
package org.yourdomain.yourproject.subpackage;
package com.gmail.youremailaddress.yourproject.subpackage;
```

It doesn't matter for tests, prototypes and similar, but please keep it in mind.

---

```
import java.util.*;
```

Please don't import whole packages. Only import things you need. A half-decent IDE should be able to manage the imports for you anyway.

---

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
```

As already said, `System.in` is not necessarily the keyboard, renaming this variable is advised.

---

```
while(kbd.hasNext())
{
```

Java uses a modified K&R-Style for braces, meaning that opening braces are on the same line.

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
```

---

```
if(num > big) { // opens If statement
```

Such comments are sign that something is wrong with your code. In this case it seems like a left-over from a previous iteration, but generally if you need to comment on braces and where they belong to, you're doing something wrong.

---

```
System.out.print(big);
System.out.print(big2);
```

Here is a bug, you'll print the output like this:

```
25984
```

You should use `println()` and some informative text:

```
System.out.println("First: " + Integer.toString(big));
System.out.println("Second: " + Integer.toString(big2));
```